# Docker on Windows 10 Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a beginner in Docker
I was trying to deploy my React app in docker
So I tried running:

```
docker build -t react_b ./
```

And when I tried it to run it:

```
docker run  -p 8080:80 react_b
```

It show the error:
`Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.`

I checked with the command `docker container ls -a`
No other containers are running
In the solutions I found, they suggested to remove/containers cause some ports are allocated there but I have no other containers running.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: Is something listening on port 80 already?  Try opening localhost in your web browser.

Comment: @StephenNewell there's nothing listening on the port 80, I checked in my browser

Comment: What happends if you try an other port than 80, f.x. ```docker run  -p 8080:81 react_b```?

Comment: @KajHejer It's giving the same error

Comment: @LisaChowdhury OK, thanks! Just fyi: I tried to build and run this image on macOS 11.2.3 but was not able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @LisaChowdhury You might want to take a look at the discussion at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20486.

Comment: @KajHejer I haven't pushed this image to docker hub yet, maybe that's why you couldn't reproduce the issue. Thanks for the discussion link